# php maintain session between page having class and another page without class

Tags: php, session

**Page1.php (Not Full code)**

```
<?php

class A {

 function Session() {
    session_start(); // assume session started here
  }

?>
<button onclick="play('MyVideo.mp4',event)">MyVideo1</button

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function play(video,e) {

            var videoFile = 'folder1/product.php?v=' + video;
            $('#divVideo video source').attr('src', videoFile);
            $("#divVideo video")[0].load();

        }
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

**product.php (this page is not a class)** 
In product.php I am having some code, but  `if(isset($_SESSION)){` condition failed ,so got to understand that session getting failed.

**How do I make session pass in product.php?** I cannot use $this in this product.php page.

Comment: Did you start the page with `session_start();`? Please show us all the code.

Comment: Actually session started in some other page. I am pretty sure, session exists in all other pages. but ptoduct.php is not a class

Comment: whichever page uses `$_SESSION` you **need** `session_start();` on that page. Preferably the first thing. Otherwise session data won't work on that page.

Comment: @Script47 I do not want to create new session in product.php

Comment: [session_start — Start new or **resume existing session**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: @John: Calling `session_start()` will only create a new session if one does not already exist.

Comment: @caCtus thank you. :)

Comment: well for the session variable in php when you verify user from db upon signing in.
put some data i.e user id name email into session object.
then any where in you pages. ie product page you can check using session object if the user is signed in or not. then allow him to download. more importantly you must include `session_start()` at that page you are checking user.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to your products.php file you would need to use ajax, then you can pass the variable from the session via ajax to your file.

At first we need to capture the session variable in hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php $_SESSION['variable_name']?>" class="sessionName" >
```

now the js file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name = $('.sessionName').val();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'products.php', // url to your file could be different 
                type : 'post',
                data : {
                    sessName: name )
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);// check console long for output and errors
                }
        });
});
</script>
```

in your products.php file

```
if (isset($_POST['sessName']) ){
    $session_name = $_POST['sessName']
     //output to console.log in case the variable is set 
    echo 'Session Variable : '.$session_name;
}else{
    //output to console.log  when variable is not set
    echo 'Session Variable is not Set'; // if not
}
```

Hope this help.